# InstallShield: Handle password with special characters

Tags: c#, special-characters, installshield-2009

I have an installer (InstallShield/ InstallScript) and during the installation process it verifies username/ password, using external simple C# application which calls Windows advapi32.dll LogonUser function. (I know that InstallShield provides its own function for verification, we had some problems with that and because of that we do this in that way).

But, when trying to handle paswords with special characters, like `Abcde"12` or `Abcde21"` , the inverted commas disappeared and the password becomes (in both cases) `Abcde12`. Surrounding it with inverted commas helped just for the second case (when the " appeared at the end). Trying to replace each instance of " with \" didn't hepl as well.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to escape the backslash as well and see if it works?
Meaning:

```
\\"
```